# How to use hybridauth plugin with CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, hybridauth

I use **CakePHP 3.x** to create a page can make a social sign in. I found HybridAuth plugin can do that. But, I can't understand about configuration and flow. Who is used to on this plugin?

Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I must thank my friend for helping me solve this mystery in cakephp 3.

I'm providing the complete options how to use the plugin in cakephp 3 may this give a solution and explore more improvements in that plugin.

**Step 1:**
Run in composer

```
php composer.phar require hybridauth/hybridauth:~2.5.0
```

This must install plugin in the following path,

```
/your-app-folder/vendor/hybridauth/..
```

**Step 2:** Initialize the plugin.

A. Modify the config.php file in the following folder,

```
/your-app-folder/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/config.php
```

to the required method, like add the app id and secret id, etc.

```
$config = array(
            "base_url" => "http://localhost/your-app-folder/users/social_redirect/",//You have to change the above according to yours

            "providers" => array(
                // openid providers
                "OpenID" => array(
                    "enabled" => true
                ),
                "Yahoo" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => ""),
                ),
                "AOL" => array(
                    "enabled" => true
                ),
                "Google" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => ""),
                ),
                "Facebook" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => ""),
                    "scope" => "email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown",
                    "trustForwarded" => false
                ),
                "Twitter" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
                // windows live
                "Live" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
                "LinkedIn" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
                "Foursquare" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
            ),
            // If you want to enable logging, set 'debug_mode' to true.
            // You can also set it to
            // - "error" To log only error messages. Useful in production
            // - "info" To log info and error messages (ignore debug messages)
            "debug_mode" => false,
            // Path to file writable by the web server. Required if 'debug_mode' is not false
            "debug_file" => "",
);
```

**Step 3:**
Now in yours users controller, (I have used users controller for http://localhost/your-app-folder/users/social - for my needs)

Now your controller should look like this,

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
      parent::beforeFilter($event);
      $this->Auth->allow(['register','social', 'social_redirect']);
    }

    public function index() {
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' =>  'add']);
    }

    public function social($provider) {

    /* Include the Config File */
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'config.php');
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'Hybrid' . DS . 'Auth.php');

    /* Initiate Hybrid_Auth Function*/
    $hybridauth = new \Hybrid_Auth($config);
    $authProvider = $hybridauth->authenticate($provider);
    $user_profile = $authProvider->getUserProfile();

    /*Modify here as per you needs. This is for demo */
    if ($user_profile && isset($user_profile->identifier)) {
        echo "<b>Name</b> :" . $user_profile->displayName . "<br>";
        echo "<b>Profile URL</b> :" . $user_profile->profileURL . "<br>";
        echo "<b>Image</b> :" . $user_profile->photoURL . "<br> ";
        echo "<img src='" . $user_profile->photoURL . "'/><br>";
        echo "<b>Email</b> :" . $user_profile->email . "<br>";
        echo "<br> <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
    }
    exit;

   /*Example Demo For FB authorize Action*/
   #Facebook authorize
    if ($this->request->params['pass'][0] == 'Facebook') {
        if ($user_profile && isset($user_profile->identifier)) {
            $this->authorize_facebook($user_profile);
        }
    } 
}

public function social_redirect() {
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'config.php');
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'Hybrid' . DS . 'Auth.php');
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'Hybrid' . DS . 'Endpoint.php');
    $hybridauth = new \Hybrid_Auth($config);
    \Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
}


public function authorize_facebook($user_profile) {

        $provider = "Facebook";
        $provider_uid = $user_profile->identifier;

        $userExist = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['Users.provider' => $provider, 'Users.provider_uid' => $user_profile->identifier])->first();


        if ((isset($userExist)) && ($userExist)) {

            $session = $this->request->session();
            $session->delete('auth_sess_var');
            $session->destroy();
            $this->Auth->setUser($userExist->toArray());
            $session->write('auth_sess_var', $userExist);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {

            /* Create new user entity */
            $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
            $tmp_hash = md5(rand(0, 1000));
            $tmp_id = time();

            /* Save individual data */
            $user->tmp_id = $tmp_id;
            $user->firstname = (!empty($user_profile->firstName)) ? $user_profile->firstName : "";
            $user->lastname = (!empty($user_profile->lastName)) ? $user_profile->lastName : "";
            $user->username = (!empty($user_profile->lastName) && !empty($user_profile->lastName)) ? strtolower($user_profile->firstName) . "." . strtolower($user_profile->lastName) : "";
            $user->avatar = (!empty($user_profile->photoURL)) ? $user_profile->photoURL : "";
            $user->role = "public";
            $user->provider = $provider;
            $user->provider_uid = $user_profile->identifier;
            $user->gender = !empty($user_profile->gender) ? (($user_profile->gender == 'male') ? 'm' : 'f' ) : "";
            $user->provider_email = !empty($user_profile->email) ? $user_profile->email : "";
            $user->password = $user_profile->identifier;
            $user->confirm_password = $user_profile->identifier;
            $user->tmp_hash = $tmp_hash;
            $user->isverified = (!empty($user_profile->emailVerified)) ? 1 : 0;
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            $this->Users->save($user);

            $userDetails = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['Users.provider' => $provider, 'Users.provider_uid' => $user_profile->identifier])->first();

            /* Destroy previous session before setting new Session */
            $session = $this->request->session();
            $session->delete('auth_sess_var');
            $session->destroy();

            /* Set user */
            $this->Auth->setUser($userDetails->toArray());
            $session->write('auth_sess_var', $userDetails);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
    }

}
```

**Note:** Modify The Things according to your needs and design the table as per you requirement.

**Step 4**

Calling the hybrid auth:

```
For Ex: <a href="/users/social/Facebook">Facebook<a>
```

for facebook login;

Eureka. It will works like a charm.

**For more info comment here.**

**Edit 2:**

Example Login Action (Default Auth Control)

In App Controller,

```
public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');

        /* Authentication */
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'controller',
                'action' => 'action'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ]
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: Thank for your support. But when I load component in AppController: $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form',
                'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth'
            ]
        ]);
I get an error: Authentication adapter "ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth" was not found.

Could you please advise me how to slove it? Many Thank

Comment: Use the default auth component for login action. Check whether the email exists in database else store the email address and provider id and then authenticate.

Comment: Could you please send me your example project?

Comment: Sorry @Luc Le I couldn't coz I integrated in confidential project. I'll seperate it and send you the file. But I need some time.

Comment: I'm getting error as `Hybriauth config does not exist on the given path.`

Comment: @PrassannaD how to login with google? i get URI mismatch error. can u please help me with the proper uri?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this page yet?
http://miftyisbored.com/complete-social-login-application-tutorial-cakephp-2-3-twitter-facebook-google/

This would help you to put hybridauth into CakePHP 3.0, but you need to change some points in CakePHP3 way, like:

```
// config/hybridauth.php

return [
  'HybridAuth' => [
    'base_url' => 'URL here',
    'providers' => [
      'Twitter' => [...]
    ]
];
```

and

```
// src/Controller/Component/HybridauthComponent.php

// App::import('Vendor', 'hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth');
// $this->hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );
$this->hybridauth = new \Hybrid_Auth( $config );
```

In addition, check this document.

https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth/blob/master/README.md

It says you need to initialize the Auth component, but it didn't work this way, so I put these options like this:

```
// src/Controller/AppController.php

public function initialize()
{
  $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
      'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth'
    ],
    // redirect here if the user not authorized
    'loginAction' => [
      'controller' => 'User',
      'action' => 'login',
    ],
   ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i got error with these code and i repaired it with:
error: Hybriauth config does not exist on the given path.

solution:
 in users controller where you call(require) config.php

```
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'config.php');
```

you need to store that what you require in variable $config:

```
$config = require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'config.php');
```