# Problems implementing cakephp auth with login facebook

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, facebook-sdk-4.0

I created an application using cakephp auth component in cakephp 2.6.2 version, now I also implement a login with facebook using facebook sdk, I am trying to follow this post [How do I integrate Facebook SDK login with cakephp 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037971/how-do-i-integrate-facebook-sdk-login-with-cakephp-2-x), and for this I have downloaded the [facebook-php-sdk-v4](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4), however when I use the sentence

```
App::import('Vendor', 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook');
```

and then call the Facebook class, I am having the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\exampleApp\app\Controller\AppController.php on line 34
```

I copied facebook SDK in exampleApp\app\Vendor
and the folder is named facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev

my appControll here

```
    <?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::import('Vendor', 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook');

class AppController extends Controller {



    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'home',
                'action' => 'Page'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )
            ),
            'authorize' => array('Controller'),
            'authError' => false
        )
    );


    public function beforeFilter(){

        $this->Facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'     =>  'App_ID_of_facebook',
            'secret'    =>  'App_Secret'

        ));

        $this->layout = 'bootstrap';
        $this->Auth->allow(
                            'login', 
                            'logout'
                    );

        $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        if(isset($user['role_id']) && $user['role_id'] === '1')
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

}
?>
```

The problem is particularly in

```
$this->Facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'     =>  'App_ID_of_facebook',
            'secret'    =>  'App_Secret'

        ));
```

is here where is returning Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found

thank you very much in advance to anyone who can help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24746915/1392379

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand precisely what I'm doing wrong, you can be more specific?

Comment: Try, Using 'HybridAuth' method http://hayageek.com/login-with-facebook-twitter-google-php/

Comment: For reference use this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511055/how-to-use-hybridauth-plugin-with-cakephp-3-x/32910020#32910020

Comment: Hello, the problem I have is that I have my application with cakephp auth component, and must implement a login with facebook with auth component, Anyone know why I can not successfully import the SDK of facebook?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the class "Vendor/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook/Facebok.php" had "namespace Facebook" therefore was in a different scope of my project, so the solution was to remove "namespace Facebook"