# CakePHP 3 : Hybriauth config does not exist on the given path

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, hybridauth

I am working on CakePHP 3 project where I have to add social login.

For that I'm using `HybridAuth` following the tutorial from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511055/how-to-use-hybridauth-plugin-with-cakephp-3-x)

Now When I access `http://website.com/users/social/Facebook` I get error as

```
Hybriauth config does not exist on the given path.
```

My `UsersController` is

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{

  public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
  {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['register','logout','social','social_redirect']);
  }

    public function login()
    {
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
          $this->Auth->setUser($user);
          return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
      }
    }

    public function social($provider)
    {
      /* Include the config file */
      require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'config.php');
      require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'Hybrid' . DS . 'Auth.php');

      /* Initiate Hybrid_Auth Function */
      $hybridauth = new \Hybrid_Auth($config);
      $authProvider = $hybridauth->authenticate($provider);
      $user_profile = $authProvider->getUserProfile();

      /* Modify here as per need. This is for demo */
      if ($user_profile && isset($user_profile->identifier)) {
        echo "<b>Name</b> : " . $user_profile->displayName . "<br />";
        echo "<b>Profile URL : </b>" . $user_profile->profileURL . "<br />";
        echo "<b>Image : </b>" . $user_profile->photoURL . "<br />";
        echo "<img src='" . $user_profile->photoURL . "'<br />";
        echo "<b>Email : </b>" . $user_profile->email . "<br />";
        echo "<br /> <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
      }
      exit;

      /* Example demo for FB authorize Action */
      #Facebook authorize
      if ($this->request->params['pass'][0] == 'Facebook') {
        if ($user_profile && isset($user_profile->identifier)) {
          $this->authorize_facebook($user_profile);
        }
      }
    }

    public function social_redirect()
    {
      $this->layout = false;
      $this->autoRender = false;
      require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'config.php');
      require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'Hybrid' . DS . 'Auth.php');
      require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'Hybrid' . DS . 'Endpoint.php');

      $hybridauth = new \Hybrid_Auth($config);
      \Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
    }

    public function authorize_facebook($user_profile)
    {
      $provider = 'Facebook';
      $provider_uid = $user_profile->identifier;

      $userExist = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['Users.provider' => $provider, 'Users.provider_uid' => $user_profile->identifier])->first();

      if ((isset($userExist)) && ($userExist)) {
        $session = $this->request->session();
        $session->delete('auth_sess_var');
        $session->destroy();
        $this->Auth->setUser($userExist->toArray());
        $session->write('auth_sess_var', $userExist);
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
      } else {

        /* Create new user entity */
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        $tmp_hash = md5(rand(0, 1000));
        $tmp_id = time();

        /* Save individual data */
        $user->tmp_id = $tmp_id;
        $firstName = (!empty($user_profile->firstName)) ? $user_profile->firstName : "";
        $lastName = (!empty($user_profile->lastName)) ? $user_profile->lastName : "";
        $user->name = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
      //  $user->username = (!empty($user_profile->firstName) && !empty($user_profile->lastName)) ? strlolower($user_profile->firstName) . "." . strtolower($user_profile->lastName) : "";
      //  $user->avatar = (!empty($user_profile->photoURL)) ? $user_profile->photoURL : "";
      //  $user->role = "public";
        $user->provider = $provider;
        $user->provider_uid = $user_profile->identifier;
        $user->email = !empty($user_profile->email) ? $user_profile->email : "";
        $user->password = $user_profile->identifier;
      //  $user->confirm_password = $user_profile->identifier;
        $user->tmp_hash = $tmp_hash;
        $user->verified = (!empty($user_profile->emailVerified)) ? 1 : 0;

        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        $this->Users->save($user);

        $userDetails = $this->Users->find('all')
          ->where(['Users.provider' => $provider, 'Users.provider_uid' => $user_profile->identifier])->first();

        /* Destroy previous session before setting new Session */
        $session = $this->request->session();
        $session->delete('auth_sess_var');
        $session->destroy();

        /* Set user */
        $this->Auth->setUser($userDetails->toArray());
        $session->write('auth_sess_var', $userDetails);
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
      }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
      return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
```

I have installed `HybridAuth : version 2.5.1` using `composer` and its location is

```
 | / root
    |- vendor
      |- hybridauth
        |- hybridauth
          |- hybridauth
            |- Hybrid (directory)
              |- Auth.php
              |- ...
            |- config.php
            |- index.php
```

content of `config.php`

```
<?php

/**
 * HybridAuth
 * http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net | http://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth
 * (c) 2009-2015, HybridAuth authors | http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/licenses.html
 */
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  HybridAuth Config file: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Configuration.html
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return
        array(
            "base_url" => "http://website.com/users/social-redirect/",
            "providers" => array(
                // openid providers
                "OpenID" => array(
                    "enabled" => true
                ),
                "Yahoo" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => ""),
                ),
                "AOL" => array(
                    "enabled" => true
                ),
                "Google" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => ""),
                ),
                "Facebook" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "id", "secret" => "key"),
                    "trustForwarded" => false
                ),
                "Twitter" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => ""),
                    "includeEmail" => false
                ),
                // windows live
                "Live" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
                "LinkedIn" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
                "Foursquare" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
            ),
            // If you want to enable logging, set 'debug_mode' to true.
            // You can also set it to
            // - "error" To log only error messages. Useful in production
            // - "info" To log info and error messages (ignore debug messages)
            "debug_mode" => false,
            // Path to file writable by the web server. Required if 'debug_mode' is not false
            "debug_file" => "",
);
```

What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: Would be easier to use my plugin https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth and follow it's readme.

Comment: Thanks I will try it today and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way to remove error:
in users controller where you call(require) config.php

```
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'config.php');
```

you need to store that what you require in variable $config:

```
$config = require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'hybridauth' . DS . 'config.php');
```

best regards